# .each only in one field

Tags: jquery, each

I have several forms with the same field and I need to collect the value of a set o field with jQuery. I'm using `.each` and it works properly for the field with `id="q"` but, I don't know why, for the others fields it gets only the first value. Someone can help me?

HTML:

```
<form name="art_1" id="art_1">
<input type="text" name="prezzol" id="prezzol">
<input type="text" name="q" id="q" onchange="ricalcola('#art_1')">
<input type="text" name="sconto" id="sconto" onchange="ricalcola('#art_1')">
</form>
<form id="art_2" name="art_2">
<input type="text" id="prezzol" name="prezzol">
<input type="text" name="q" id="q" onchange="ricalcola('#art_2')" >
<input type="text" name="sconto" id="sconto" onchange="ricalcola('#art_2')" >
</form>
<a onclick="totale()">totale</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
function totale() {
    $('#q').each(function (){
    //works!! 2 value!
    tquantità += parseInt($(this).val())
}) 
$('#sconto').each(function(){
    //doesn't work, only the first value
    tprezzo += $(this).val()
})
```

Comment: why you use .each to select an element with ID!!??

Comment: use class insted of ID.... ID should always be unique thats why it is called "ID" bytheway.....

Answer (score 0):

ID's are supposed to be unique so that's why you'll only get one value back.

Try using the name of your input for the selector.  i.e.:
    $('input[name=q]')

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple `id`s on the same document .. change your HTML to use classes instead and then iterate of the elements

```
<form name="art_1" id="art_1">
<input type="text" name="prezzol" class="prezzol">
<input type="text" name="q" class="q" onchange="ricalcola('#art_1')">
<input type="text" name="sconto" class="sconto" onchange="ricalcola('#art_1')">
</form>
<form id="art_2" name="art_2">
<input type="text" class="prezzol" name="prezzol">
<input type="text" name="q" class="q" onchange="ricalcola('#art_2')" >
<input type="text" name="sconto" class="sconto" onchange="ricalcola('#art_2')" >
</form>
<a onclick="totale()">totale</a>
```

then do

```
function totale() {
    $('.q').each(function (){
      tquantità += parseInt($(this).val(),10);
    }) 
    $('.sconto').each(function(){
       tprezzo += parseInt($(this).val(),10);
    })
})
```

And [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) should always include the radix

Answer (score 0):

if you want to select all element with name attribute you can use this code :

```
function totale() {
    $('input[name=sconto]').each(function (){
      tquantità += parseInt($(this).val(),10);
    }) 
    $('input[name=q]').each(function(){
       tprezzo += parseInt($(this).val(),10);
    })
})
```